# Sending commands to console installer in docker

Tags: bash, docker, installation

I am trying to install inspectIT in my docker container, however it seems as if they only package an installer that I must go through.
This seems rather difficult but I was thinking: is it possible to send commands to a console application?

for example if I start the installer it will get to a point like this

```
Press 1 to continue, 2 to quit, 3 to redisplay
```

Can I send a command to it or script it in some way in order to install it on docker?

Comment: Is it the only moment in your install script you have an interactive prompt ?

Comment: You checked that they do not offer a "silent" installation or a way to provide the selections upfront via command line arguments?

Comment: I have not found any silent options, but it seems as if you are right @Aserre and this is a duplicate